# Querying datetime.datetime on appengine acts different then dev server help!

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having some trouble with stuff that work locally and dont work on the app engine python environment:

Basically, i want to get a program from an epg between ranges of date and time.
i know i cannot do two where > < so i saw a suggestion to save the dates as list as datetime.datetime which i did.

```
[datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 10, 14, 25), datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 10, 15, 0)]
```

This is ok. but when i try to compare to it:

```
progranon = get_object(Programs2Channel, 
                           'channel_id =', channelobj.key(),
                           'endstartdate >', programstart_minex, 
                           'endstartdate <', programstart_minex
                           )
```

This for some reason works locally, but fails to retrieve the data on the app engine.

*Im using Google app engine django patch which uses the get_object to retrieve data in transactions.

Please help.

Here are more details:

this is the LIST:

```
[datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 13, 10, 45), datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 13, 11, 30)]

#this is the query:

programstart = ""+year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hour+":"+minute
programstart_minex = datetime.strptime(programstart, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

progranon = Programs2Channel.gql('WHERE channel_id = :channelid AND endstartdate > :programstartx AND endstartdate < :programstartx',channelid = channelobj.key(),programstartx=programstart_minex).get()
```

Comment: that query returns nothing. None object.

Comment: Please note. This WORKS locally. i've also noticed that the dev_server saved the :SECONDS also and the app engine doesnt. why?

Answer (score 1):

could this be the issue?

From:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html

> a datetime, date, or time literal,
>   with either numeric values or a string
>   representation, in the following
>   forms: DATETIME(year, month, day,
>   hour, minute, second)
>   DATETIME('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')

my local server dev saves the datetime as numerical YYYY-MM-DD while the app engine saves datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 10, 14, 25),

LOCAL datetime list:

```
2010-05-09 08:30:00,2010-05-09 09:00:00
```

APP ENGINE LIST:

```
[datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 13, 10, 45), datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 13, 11, 30)]
```

maybe this is the issue?

Comment: i came to a conclusion that you cannot compare > < to list anymore on the app engine. can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue with the dev_appserver and querying on lists.

However, the dev_appserver now includes an experimental sqlite stub, which doesn't have this issue. Try running it with --use_sqlite, and see if that helps - it should!

Comment: It does work locally on the dev server, so i should trust if it works on the local dev server?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry. Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

How about querying just querying for programs that start after mindate (just the > query) and then filtering in memory?
If its a TV Guide, we're not talking thousand of possible entities right?  probably ~100 tops?